# OpenCV Вырезать найденные шаблоны

Tags: python, opencv

Есть небольшая программа, которая ищет на изображении заданные элементы и сохраняет новое изображение с обведенными, найденными элементами.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread('mario.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('mario_template.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

Вопрос, как вырезать и сохранить найденные элементы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скопировать прямоугольный кусок  - установить ROI в координаты прямоугольника, скопировать в новое изображение, сбросить ROI

```
  cvSetImageROI(Image, rc);
  cvCopyImage(image, imgtmp, nil);
  cvResetImageROI(Image);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как получить координаты прямоугольника.

Comment: Как я понимаю, они у вас используются в `cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)`